# undefined method `response_body=' for #<Grape::API:0x007fd8c71f17b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-grape

I'm writing testing code for api created by grape in rails. There's an error: undefined method `response_body=' for #
does anyone knows the reason and how to fix this? I'll be very thankful for that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is trying to set the value of response_body, which does not seem like  what you want to do. The error is telling you that there is no setter for the attribute...